# Show/Hide items in a 3D model using HTML checkbox

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d-modelling, 3d-model

I have developed a 3D Model using JavaScript, CSS and Three.js.

The whole project consists of 5 JS files, 1 CSS file and 1 HTML file.

The Model looks like this:

[[image: 3D model]]

I have added showers for each cubicle and I need to show them only when the user checks the checkbox for specific cubicle.

For instance, if the user selects the 'cubicle 1 checkbox', shower should be shown in the cubicle 1.

Related code chunk of responsible JavaScript file:

```
  function createPartition() {
    var partitionGroup = new THREE.Group();
    var door = new THREE.Mesh(geometries.door, materials.doorMaterial);
    var doorLibbing = new THREE.Mesh(geometries.libbing1, materials.libbingMaterial);
    var frontPanelWithoutHoles = new THREE.Mesh(geometries.frontPanelWithoutHoles, materials.frontPanelMaterial);
    var frontPanelWithHoles = new THREE.Mesh(geometries.frontPanelWithHoles, materials.frontPanelMaterial);
    var frontPanel_leftLibbing = new THREE.Mesh(geometries.libbing2, materials.libbingMaterial);
    var frontPanel_rightLibbing = new THREE.Mesh(geometries.libbing2, materials.libbingMaterial);
    var frontPanel_topLibbing = new THREE.Mesh(geometries.libbing2, materials.libbingMaterial);
    var partitionLeft = new THREE.Mesh(geometries.partition, materials.partitionMaterial);
    var partitionLeft_frontLibbing = new THREE.Mesh(geometries.libbing2, materials.libbingMaterial);
    var partitionLeft_backLibbing = new THREE.Mesh(geometries.libbing2, materials.libbingMaterial);
    var partitionLeft_topLibbing = new THREE.Mesh(geometries.libbing2, materials.libbingMaterial);


  var wallMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color:resources.settings.wallColor});


    footRight = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(.040, .15, 0.05), wallMaterial);
    footLeft = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(.040, .15, 0.05), wallMaterial);
```

> shower= new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(0.1, 0.11, 0.45),
>   wallMaterial);
>           showerhead= new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(0.1, 0.1, -0.04), wallMaterial);

```
    partitionLeft.add(footRight);
    partitionLeft.add(footLeft);
```

> partitionLeft.add(shower); 
>           partitionLeft.add(showerhead);

```
    footRight.position.set(-0.12,-0.85,0);
    footLeft.position.set(.12,-0.85,0);
```

> shower.position.set(0.4,0.5,-1.312);
>           showerhead.position.set(0.4,0.4,-1.112);

I include the checkbox values in index.html

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cube1" value="cube1"> Cubicle 1<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="cube2" value="cube2" checked> Cubicle 2 <br>
```

Any suggestion how to show the 'shower' when a user checks a specific checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using pure JavaScript, you can initially hide your shower by having a class on shower and in your css have it display: none; and assume your I shower heads have ID's.

In your css file it would look something like this

```
#showerHead1{
     display:none;
}
.displayShower{
     display:block;
}
```

Then have an if statement to see if the checkbox for cube1 or cube 2 is checked then execute

document.getElementById("showerHead1").className = "displayShower";

which should override the showerHead1 class in css.

If you want to remove the class then you would call document.getElementById("showerHead1").classList.remove("displayShower");

Here are my references

add class
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_classname.asp

remove class
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_remove_class.asp

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Javascript in your code, you can add onclick event to the button and add one external function where you can add or remove that particular mesh.

I tried it and it works for me.

Hope this will help you too.

Answer (score 0):

A very rough concept of how you can do it:

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 3, 5);
camera.lookAt(scene.position);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

function makeCubicle(id, color, position, isShown) {

  var cubicle = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(2, 3, 2), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: color,
    wireframe: true
  }));
  cubicle.position.copy(position);
  cubicle.visible = isShown;
  scene.add(cubicle);

  var id = "cubicle" + id;
  var chbx = document.createElement("INPUT");
  chbx.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
  chbx.checked = isShown;
  chbx.id = id;
  chbx.addEventListener("click", function() {
    cubicle.visible = !cubicle.visible;
  });

  chbxContainer.appendChild(chbx);
}

makeCubicle("1", "red", new THREE.Vector3(-2, 0, 0), true);
makeCubicle("2", "blue", new THREE.Vector3(2, 0, 0), false);

render();

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}

#chbxContainer {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/93/three.min.js"></script>
<div id="chbxContainer"></div>
```